# seleccionar la ultima palabra de la frase y convertirla en negrita

Tags: javascript, html

tengo otro problema con las funciones de cadena, si intento convertir el texto en negrita de todas las cadenas que estan en un indice par de mi array no tengo ningun problema, el codigo para eso es el siguiente

```
lineas.map(function(value, indice){
 lineas[indice] = lineas[indice].replace(lineas[indice], "<strong>"+lineas[indice]+"</strong>"))
})
```

transforma todo el texto en negrita, sin embargo si intento poner en negrita solo las ultimas palabras de cada frase, recibo malos resultados

```
<p id="poesia">
LA SCARPETTA
Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta
guarda che ti sei persa la scarpetta.
io stamattina l’ho trovata
con la carrozza ieri sei scappata.
E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare
il Cuore tu mi hai fatto sussultare,
</p>
<button onclick="iterare()">iterar</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  texto = document.getElementById('poesia').textContent;


  lineas = texto.split(/\n/); // division por saltos de linea
 /*
    ["", "LA SCARPETTA", "Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta", "guarda che ti sei persa la scarpetta.", "io stamattina l’ho trovata", "con la carrozza ieri sei scappata.", "E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare", "il Cuore tu mi hai fatto sussultare,", ""]
  */ 


  lineas[2] = lineas[2].replace(lineas[2].slice(0, -3), "<strong>"+lineas[2].slice(-3)+"</strong>");
  // "<strong>tta</strong>tta"

  /* resultado esperado
  mi sa che ieri sera eri di </strong>fretta</strong> */



</script>
```

ademas no se porque razon se generan dos comillas vacias al inicio y al final del array

Answer (score 2):

Para cambiar la ultima palabra de cada frase de la Poesía , se me ocurre realizar un `split` al elemento y accediendo al ultimo valor con `pop()` para luego aplicar el `slice` desde la posición `0` hasta la posición total **menos (-)** el `length` del elemento obtenido con `pop()` , así luego se concatenará añadiendo las negritas (`<b>`)

```js
function iterare(){
  texto = document.getElementById('poesia').textContent;
  lineas = texto.split(/\n/);
  lineas.map(function(value, indice){
  let last =  value.split(" ").pop();
  lineas[indice]= lineas[indice].slice(0, lineas[indice].length-last.length)+"<b>"+last+ "</b>";
  });
   document.getElementById('poesia').innerHTML = lineas.join("<br>"); 
 }
```

```html
<p id="poesia">
LA SCARPETTA
Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta
guarda che ti sei persa la scarpetta.
io stamattina l’ho trovata
con la carrozza ieri sei scappata.
E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare
il Cuore tu mi hai fatto sussultare,
</p>
<button onclick="iterare()">iterar</button>
```

Comment: disculpa pero no entendi porque a la funcion slice le pasas como parametro  dos lengths con un guion, luego no entiendo si lo dividiste por espacios porque luego lo concatenas con <br>, aclarame las dudas, gracias

Comment: Slice recibe dos parámetros el inicio o sea 0, y el final que será el `length;` de value **-** el length del la última palabra obtenida con `pop` ya que el length de este último será variable, una vez obtenido esto se concatena con el valor de pop pero añadiendo las negritas. El último paso del  `join` lo hice por estética para añadir un salto de línea y se visualizará mejor en el documento.

Answer (score 1):

Primero creas un *arrays* dividiendo el string ***lineas[2]*** en palabras `Words = lineas[2].split(" ")`, luego eliminas la ultima palabra del *arrays* `lastWord = Words.pop()` (este a su vez devuelve el valor eliminado) y por ultimo restableces el *string* con `Words.join(" ")`;

```js
  texto = document.getElementById('poesia').textContent;


  lineas = texto.split(/\n/); // division por saltos de linea
 /*
    ["", "LA SCARPETTA", "Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta", "guarda che ti sei persa la scarpetta.", "io stamattina l’ho trovata", "con la carrozza ieri sei scappata.", "E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare", "il Cuore tu mi hai fatto sussultare,", ""]
  */ 

  Words = lineas[2].split(" ");
  lastWord = Words.pop();
  lineas[2] =  lineas[2].replace(lineas[2], Words.join(" ")+" <strong>"+lastWord+"</strong>");
  // "<strong>tta</strong>tta"

  /* resultado esperado
  mi sa che ieri sera eri di </strong>fretta</strong> */
  console.log(lineas[2]);
```

```html
<pre id="poesia">
LA SCARPETTA
Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta
guarda che ti sei persa la scarpetta.
io stamattina l’ho trovata
con la carrozza ieri sei scappata.
E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare
il Cuore tu mi hai fatto sussultare,
</pre>
<button onclick="iterare()">iterar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba el siguiente script, primero separamos los renglones en un arreglo, luego cada renglón lo separamos por palabras para agregarle la etiqueta"**strong**" a la ultima palabra con "**palabras.length-1**"

```
texto = document.getElementById('poesia').textContent;
var lineas = texto.split(/\n/);
var linea;
for (var i = 0, i < lineas.length; i++) {
    linea = lineas[i];
    palabras = texto.split(" ");
    palabras[palabras.length-1]="<strong>"+palabras[palabras.length-1]+"</strong>"
}
document.getElementById('poesia').innerHTML = lineas.join("<br>");
```